# drawing rectangle

Tags: java, drawing, shapes

I am writing a program that accepts coordinates from the user and drawing some shapes on the screen with stars(*)

e.g Rectangle i.e rectangle=100,150,50,50 as x,y,width,height. how can I do it??

Comment: no only on the screen with stars

Comment: Can you list all the shapes you need to support?

Comment: rectangle,triangleisquare and pentagon..I will accept the coordinates from the user

Comment: you will require different attributes for different shapes right? width and height would be enough for just rectangle...

Comment: Well before we delve into a solution for the issue. There is another based on the information you have provided. What mechanism will you employ to determine what type of shape you are dealing with? If they only pass in coordinates like (Point[] for example) then you are in for a nightmare of determining the shape.

Comment: but i need also start points x and y

Comment: i should do it with for loops right?

Comment: Is there any other way to do??

Comment: This smells of homework so if it is please tag it appropriately. Issues to solve: Create a mechanism for knowing the type of shape you are handling. A good solution will also solve the issue for the attributes to pass in. Start with a basic shape class and then look at extending through composition or inheritance where necessary. Once you have done this for all your shapes. Then you are ready for the original question of how to render them using asterisks.

Comment: Write a program that will draw a picture on the screen based on parameters. The program will
have 5 options
a. Will accept coordinates for following shape types
i. Rectangle i.e Rectangle=100,200,50,50 as x,y,width,height
ii. Triangle i.e Triangle=100,200,50,50,60,60 as x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2
iii. Square i.e Square=100,200,50 as x,y,length
iv. Pentagon i.e Pentagon=100,200,50,50,60,60 as x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4
b. Exit

Comment: may be the coordinates of the point from where the rectangle is draen

Comment: Please can you describe your question better so we can help you.

Comment: Please don't ask this question again just because you are unhappy with the answers given.  You can edit your question to clarify it.  You can also offer a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this tutorial is very useful for you: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html

Comment: thank you Alex but i wont use GUI i will just draw shapes with for loops.

Answer (score 1):

What 'drawing with stars' is? If this is text mode with  monospaced font, you'll need to print it in horizontal lines  of stars, calculating right lengths. For rectangles this is easy, for triangles, a bit less easy, pentagon is just a combination of a rectangle and some triangles. See [Bresenham algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham_algorithm) for inspiration.

Also note that text mode resolution is quite poor; standard terminal window in only 80 chars wide, and you can hardly have it far wider than say 200-300 chars, so correct rounding is important.

Comment: pentagon is not very hard to break down into easy pieces: ![4 triangles and a rectangle](http://i.min.us/idH51K.png).

Answer (score 0):

If it's only rectangles, then putting the following in your paint method should work...

```
int xIncrement = (int)g.getFont().getStringBounds("*", null).getWidth();  
int yIncrement = (int)g.getFont().getStringBounds("*", null).getHeight(); 
for(int i = y; i < y + height; i += xIncrement)  
    for(int j = x; j < x + width; j += yIncrement)
        g.drawString("*", j, i);
```

For triangles and other shapes it's a bit tougher, but you can figures out the gradients of the lines separating the points, and therefore get the initial x for each line.

Generally, try to avoid 'star drawing'...

Answer (score 0):

Below is from [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#Rectangle%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

> x - the new x coordinate for the
>   top-left corner of this Rectangle y -
>   the new y coordinate for the top-left
>   corner of this Rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are referring to GUI, the Y coordinate can be the amount of lines you have to 'skip' and the x coordinate resemble the amount of spaces you have enter in the line.

So basically, x = 2 and y = 3 means that you will have to go down 3 lines and move 2 spaces to the right.